# Yii dynamic menu creation jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, yii

I have set-up a JQuery Mobile site and now I am creating a CMS using the Yii Framework.

I have a database table set-up for the menu creation that is linked to another table for the page content.

The menu table has:
ID, Title, Parent, Collapsible (collapsible is a checkbox used to determine whether to create a page for that given menu item as I don't want collapsible items to be click-able as you can see from the jsFiddle below)

jsfiddle.net/gn7q6/

From the jsFiddle above you can see how I want the menu to function.

I'm just unsure of how to create a dynamic menu this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have setup the model Menu for MenuTable and there has defined the relation

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'childMenuItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Menu', 'parent_id'),
    );
}
```

Getting top parent menus

```
// the parent menu would not have parent menu id (0, empty or IS NULL, my case was using comapare with 0 as default FK column value)
$topMenus = Menu::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('parent_id' => '0'));
```

To render the menu

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<?php 
$render = "";
echo renderMenuItems(topMenus, &$render);
}?>
</ul>
```

the function which handles recursive n-sub-menus rendering

```
<?php 
function renderMenuItems($parentItem, &$render){
        if(count($parentItem->childMenuItems) > 0){
            $render .= '<li class="custom-li">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" class="custom-collapsible2" data-iconpos="right">
                        <h3><?php echo $parentItem->title ?></h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview">';
                        foreach($parentItem->childMenuItems as $item){
                            $render .= renderMenuItems($parentItem,$render);
                        }

            $render .= '</ul>
                    </div>
                </li>';         
        }
        else{
            $render .= '<li><a href="<?php echo $menu->actionUrl ?>"><?php echo $menu->title ?></a></li>';
        }
        return $render;
    }
    ?>
```

I did not debug it yet, but the idea is the same. Not just this menu, the logic of many other menus will be almost same if there has repetition of layout structure on their sub-level menu